# How is a p-value computed for regression coefficients, and why does it remain unchanged when regressors are standardized?

Tags: regression

I have seen a lot of posts on p-values for regression coefficients that these R/Python packages output, but I've never actually learned how to compute them myself.

In linear regression, how do you go about computing the p-value? In addition, why does the p-value not change when you standardize the regressors (perhaps knowing the method for computation will help me realize the second question).

Comment: I started to derive this, but there is quite a bit that must be explained.  I think rather than have anyone type out all the necessary notation, framework, and derivations, I'll just refer you to Chapters 1 and 2 of `Kutner, M. H., Nachtsheim, C. J., Neter, J., &amp; Li, W. (2005). Applied linear statistical models. New York: McGrawHill Education.` and Chapter 5 if you are interested in how to derive this for multiple linear regression.

https://d1b10bmlvqabco.cloudfront.net/attach/is282rqc4001vv/is6ccr3fl0e37q/iwfnjvgvl53z/Michael_H_Kutner_Christopher_J._Nachtsheim_JohnBookFi.org.pdf

Comment: Chapter 7, section 7.5 also details why the p-value will not change after standardizing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I have seen a lot of posts on p-values for regression coefficients
> that these R/Python packages output, but I've never actually learned
> how to compute them myself. In linear regression, how do you go about
> computing the p-value?

The book by Knuter *et al.*, recommended by StatsStudent, is a bit old but still very useful. They do not use R (nor Python), but their data sets are plain text files and you can easily download them and use whatever software you like. For example, download [http://users.stat.ufl.edu/~rrandles/sta4210/Rclassnotes/data/textdatasets/KutnerData/Chapter%20%206%20Data%20Sets/CH06FI05.txt](http://users.stat.ufl.edu/%7Errandles/sta4210/Rclassnotes/data/textdatasets/KutnerData/Chapter%20%206%20Data%20Sets/CH06FI05.txt), then in R:

```
> dwaine <- read.table("CH06FI05.txt", col.names=c("targetpop", "dispoinc", "sales"))
> str(dwaine)
'data.frame':   21 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ targetpop: num  68.5 45.2 91.3 47.8 46.9 66.1 49.5 52 48.9 38.4 ...
 $ dispoinc : num  16.7 16.8 18.2 16.3 17.3 18.2 15.9 17.2 16.6 16 ...
 $ sales    : num  174 164 244 155 182 ...
```

In general, your model is $\mathbf{y}=\mathbf{X}\boldsymbol{\beta}+\boldsymbol{\epsilon}$, where $\mathbf{y}$ and $\boldsymbol{\epsilon}$ are $n\times 1$ vectors, $\mathbf{X}$ is a $n\times p$ matrix, and $\boldsymbol{\beta}$ is a $p\times 1$ vector. Let's assume that $\mathbf{X}$ is nonstochastic, $\boldsymbol{\epsilon}\sim\mathcal{N}(0,\sigma^2\mathbf{I})$, so $\mathbf{y}\sim\mathcal{N}(\mathbf{X}\boldsymbol{\beta},\sigma^2\mathbf{I})$.

You estimate $\boldsymbol{\beta}$ by
$$\hat{\boldsymbol{\beta}}=(\mathbf{X}^T\mathbf{X})^{-1}\mathbf{X}^T\mathbf{y}=\mathbf{S}\mathbf{X}^T\mathbf{y},\qquad \mathbf{S}=(\mathbf{X}^T\mathbf{X})^{-1}$$

```
> y <- dwaine$sales
> X <- model.matrix(~ targetpop + dispoinc, data=dwaine)
> n <- nrow(X)
> p <- ncol(X)
> S <- solve(t(X) %*% X)
> (beta_hat <- S %*% t(X) %*% y)
                 [,1]
(Intercept) -68.85707
targetpop     1.45456
dispoinc      9.36550
```

and you have:
\begin{align*}
E[\hat{\boldsymbol{\beta}}]&=(\mathbf{X}^T\mathbf{X})^{-1}\mathbf{X}^TE[\mathbf{y}]=(\mathbf{X}^T\mathbf{X})^{-1}(\mathbf{X}^T\mathbf{X})\boldsymbol{\beta}=\boldsymbol{\beta}\\
\text{cov}(\hat{\boldsymbol{\beta}})&=(\mathbf{X}^T\mathbf{X})^{-1}\mathbf{X}^T\text{cov}(\mathbf{y})(\mathbf{X}^T\mathbf{X})^{-1}\mathbf{X}^T=\sigma^2(\mathbf{X}^T\mathbf{X})^{-1}=\sigma^2\mathbf{S}
\end{align*}
You don't know $\sigma^2$, but you can use the residual mean square to estimate it. The fitted values and the residuals are:
\begin{align*}\hat{\mathbf{y}}&=\mathbf{X}\hat{\boldsymbol{\beta}}=\mathbf{X}(\mathbf{X}^T\mathbf{X})^{-1}\mathbf{X}^T\mathbf{y}=\mathbf{Hy}&\qquad\mathbf{H}=\mathbf{X}(\mathbf{X}^T\mathbf{X})^{-1}\mathbf{X}^T\\
\mathbf{e}&=\mathbf{y}-\hat{\mathbf{y}}=\mathbf{y}-\mathbf{Hy}=(\mathbf{I}-\mathbf{H})\mathbf{y}
\end{align*}

```
> H <- X %*% S %*% t(X)
> Id <- diag(n)
> e <- (Id - H) %*% y
```

The residual sum of squares and the residual mean square are:
\begin{align*}
RSS &= \sum_{i=1}^n(y_i-\hat{y}_i)^2=\sum_{i=1}^ne_i^2=\mathbf{e}^T\mathbf{e} \\
RMS &= \frac{RSS}{n-p}=\frac{1}{n-p}\mathbf{e}^T\mathbf{e}
\end{align*}
because $RSS$ has $n-p$ degrees of freedom associated with it: $p$ degrees of freedom are lost because $p=3$ parameters (intercept, coefficients of `targetpop` and `dispoinc`) had to be estimated in obtaining the estimated means $\hat{y}_i$.

```
> (RMS <- as.vector((t(e) %*% e) / (n-p)))
[1] 121.1626
```

To get the p-values you use the test statistics:
$$t^*_j=\frac{\hat{\beta}_j-\beta_j}{\sqrt{s_{jj}RMS}}\sim t_{n-p},\qquad j=1,\dots,p$$
where the null hypothesis is $\beta_j=0$ and $s_{jj}$ is the $j$th diagonal element of $\mathbf{S}$. The denominators are called *standard errors*:

```
> (std_err <- sqrt(diag(S)*RMS))
(Intercept)   targetpop    dispoinc 
 60.0169532   0.2117817   4.0639581 
> (t_star <- beta_hat / std_err)
                 [,1]
(Intercept) -1.147294
targetpop    6.868201
dispoinc     2.304527
```

Finally:

```
> p_value <- pt(abs(t_star), n-p, lower.tail=FALSE) +   # P(t >  |tstar|)
+ pt(-abs(t_star), n-p)                                 # P(t < -|tstar|)
> p_value
                    [,1]
(Intercept) 2.662817e-01
targetpop   2.001691e-06
dispoinc    3.332136e-02
```

This is how you can replicate R output:

```
> summary(lm(sales ~ targetpop + dispoinc, data=dwaine))$coefficients
             Estimate Std. Error   t value     Pr(>|t|)
(Intercept) -68.85707 60.0169532 -1.147294 2.662817e-01
targetpop     1.45456  0.2117817  6.868201 2.001691e-06
dispoinc      9.36550  4.0639581  2.304527 3.332136e-02
```

*Caveat*: Using $(\mathbf{X}^T\mathbf{X})^{-1}\mathbf{X}^T\mathbf{y}$ to estimate $\hat{\boldsymbol{\beta}}$ is *not* a good idea, because of potential large rounding errors in real applications. Better computational methods are based on matrix decompositions. The above code is just a translation from theory to R code.

> In addition, why does the p-value not change when you standardize the regressors?

If you standardize the regressors, the p-value for the intercept vanishes because the intercept cannot but coincide with $\overline{y}$. Other p-values do not change, because...

A. The fitted values $\hat{\mathbf{y}}=\mathbf{Hy}$ are an orthogonal projection of $\mathbf{y}$ onto the vector space generated the columns in the matrix model $\mathbf{X}$. The projection matrix $\mathbf{H}$ *does not change* if you scale $\mathbf{X}$'s colums $2,\dots,p$, because these columns are just a base of that vector spaces and there are infinitely many bases. For example:
$$\mathbf{X}=\begin{bmatrix} 1 & x_1 \\ 1 & x_2 \\ 1 & x_3 \end{bmatrix},\qquad \widetilde{\mathbf{X}}=\begin{bmatrix}1 & \frac{x_1-\overline{x}}{\sigma_x} \\ 1 & \frac{x_2-\overline{x}}{\sigma_x} \\ 1 & \frac{x_3-\overline{x}}{\sigma_x}\end{bmatrix}$$
The second column in $\widetilde{\mathbf{X}}$ is a linear combination of the columns in $\mathbf{X}$:
$$\widetilde{\mathbf{X}}_{.2}=\frac{1}{\sigma_x}\mathbf{X}_{.2}-\frac{\overline{x}}{\sigma_x}\mathbf{X}_{.1}$$
So the columns in $\widetilde{\mathbf{X}}$ are another base of the same vector space and this is why the $\mathbf{H}$ matrix does not change. This means that *residuals and $RMS$ do not change*:

```
> Xstd <- model.matrix(~ scale(targetpop) + scale(dispoinc), data=dwaine)
> Sstd <- solve(t(Xstd) %*% Xstd)
> Hstd <- Xstd %*% Sstd %*% t(Xstd)
> Id <- diag(n)
> e <- (Id - Hstd) %*% y
> (RMS <- as.vector((t(e) %*% e) / (n-p)))
[1] 121.1626
```

B. If you divide a regressor by $c$, its coefficient is multiplied by $c$. If you subract $d$ from a regressor, its coefficient does not change (but the intercept does change). So if $\mathbf{X}_{.j}$ is replaced by $\widetilde{\mathbf{X}}_{.j}=(\mathbf{X}_{.j}-\overline{\mathbf{X}}_{.j})/\sigma_{\mathbf{X}_{.j}}$,  $\hat{\boldsymbol{\beta}}_j$ gets multiplied by $\sigma_{\mathbf{X}_{.j}}$:

```
> beta_hat_std <- Sstd %*% t(Xstd) %*% y
> as.vector(beta_hat_std)[2:p]
[1] 27.084377  9.087776
> as.vector(beta_hat * apply(X, 2, sd))[2:p]
[1] 27.084377  9.087776
```

As to $\sqrt{s_{jj}}$, $\mathbf{S}=(\mathbf{X}^T\mathbf{X})^{-1}$ is a complicated obiect (see Seber & Lee, *Linear Regression Analysis*, John Wiley & Sons, 2003, Example 4.6), but you can easily verify that $\sqrt{s_{jj}}$ also gets multiplied by $\sigma_{\mathbf{X}_{.j}}$:

```
> as.vector(sqrt(diag(Sstd[2:p,2:p])))
[1] 0.3582544 0.3582544
> as.vector(sqrt(diag(S[2:p,2:p])) * apply(X[,2:p], 2, sd))
[1] 0.3582544 0.3582544
```

Therefore the $t^*$ test statistic, and p-value, for every regression coefficient (except for the intercept) do not change:

```
> summary(lm(sales~ scale(targetpop) + scale(dispoinc), data=dwaine))$coefficients[2:p,]
                  Estimate Std. Error  t value     Pr(>|t|)
scale(targetpop) 27.084377   3.943446 6.868201 2.001691e-06
scale(dispoinc)   9.087776   3.943446 2.304527 3.332136e-02
```

Comment: In your equation for the test-statistic, does the t-stat not change when standardizing because the numerator and denominator increase/decreasing by the same factor?

Comment: @user5965026 Sorry, I forgot yuor second question :) I'm going to edit my answer.

Comment: You are much braver than I, Sergio.  I made it about 1/4 of the way through this material and decided to just post a link.  +10

Comment: @user5965026 Edited. HTH.

Comment: @StatsStudent I've just used some old notes of mine. I read that book several years ago, but I always take notes when I read a good book, and I hope that user5965026 will take your advice!

Comment: Is the "test statistic" that you are referring to also sometimes referred to as "t score" and "t value?" The terminology is a little confusing to me across difference resources, and I'm not sure if there's much uniformity on that matter either.